# Why DbSet<> not works with asp.net core web application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm working on an ASP.Net Core Web Application. While trying to set the dbset<>, I get this error. 
This line of code gives error:
 `public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }`
Resharper suggests two options:

- System.Data.Entity.
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.

`public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }`

Can anyone please explain which one to chose: the first or second option?

I have included the necessary references.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using DbContext = System.Data.Entity.DbContext;
```

I see this error: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`using` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) is a shortcut to allow you to write just `DbSet` instead of `System.Data.Entity.DbSet`, for example.

But both `System.Data.Entity` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` have a `DbSet` class, so it doesn't know which one to use, and it's not going to choose for you. So you have to tell it.

That said, you shouldn't be using both. Entity Framework 6 and Entity Framework Core are two completely different things. `System.Data.Entity` is for EF 6, and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` is for EF Core.

You probably shouldn't be using `System.Data.Entity`.

Comment: Thanks guys. Now that I only use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkcore, this method starts complaining:     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

Comment: Your declaration is wrong. Look at the example `OnModelCreating` method here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/

Answer (score 0):

The reason is Ambigous Reference:
that DbSet<> is defined in both `System.Data.Entity` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

Since you are working with ASPNET Core, recommended is to use `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`